# combine $n$ vectors using $L2-normalization$

Tags: algorithms, vector

Suppose that I have the following vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ $\in R^n$,$n= 9$. What I want to do exactly is to combine these $3$ vectors into $1$ representative vector $V$.

---

According to the following article: *Document Classification and Page Stream Segmentation for Digital Mailroom Applications*

- they Perform at first average pooling or just the mean of the $3$
  vectors to obtain a single representation of the $3$ vectors
- The new vector is then *L2-Normalized*

---

This is how I interpreted these steps by using the following example:

$v_1 = \ [ x_1,x_2,...,x_n \ ]$

$v_2 = \ [ y_1,y_2,...,y_n \ ]$

$v_3 = \ [ z_1,z_2,...,z_n \ ]$

**Step 1: Average Pooling**

$V = \frac{v_1 + v_2 + v_3}{3}$

$V = \ [ w_1,w_2,...,w_n \ ]$

$V$ is the vector after the average pooling or mean

---

**Step 2: L2-Norm**

$Norm = \sqrt{w_1^2+\ldots+w_n^2}$

---

**Step 3 : divide the components $w_i$ of $V$ by the $Norm$**

Are these steps correct?

---

Code Sample :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     const int size = 5;
     vector<float> v1{1,1,1,1,1};
     vector<float> v2{1,1,1,1,1};
     vector<float> v3{1,1,1,1,1};
     vector<vector<float>> V;
     V.push_back(v1);
     V.push_back(v2);
     V.push_back(v3);
     vector<float> doc(size,0.0);
     //============================================//
     //STEP 1: Average Pooling
     for(size_t i = 0; i < V.size();i++)
     {
         for(size_t j = 0; j < 5;j++)
         {
             doc[j] += V[i][j];
         }
     }

     for(size_t i = 0; i < doc.size();i++)
     {
        doc[i]= doc[i]/(float) V.size();
     }
    //============================================//
    //STEP 2: L2-Normalization
     float y =  *max_element(std::begin(doc), std::end(doc));
     float m_sum = 0.0;

     for (int k = 0; k < doc.size(); k++)
     {
        m_sum +=  pow(doc[k]/y,2);
     }
     //STEP 3: Divide components by the Norm (m_sum)
     for(size_t i = 0; i < V.size();i++)
     {
        cout << doc[i]/sqrt(m_sum)<<"  ";
     }
     cout << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My interpretation of this sentence is the same as yours, and I would have implemented the algorithm the same way.

Comment: ok @Wolfgang Bangerth thank you. Sounds good to me